# ¿Cómo abrir un pdf que se encuentra en la carpeta raw o en la carpeta assets de mi aplicación android?

Tags: java, android

Estoy comenzando en temas de android y necesito saber como abrir un archivo pdf que se encuentra en carpeta `/raw` o en la carpeta `/assets` de mi aplicación trabajo con Android Studio.

Indistintamente abrirlo con una .apk instalada en el dispositivo o internamente en la aplicación.

Comment: Hola! Te recomiendo que anexes el código en el que intentas abrir el archivo PDF, y así los personajes que responden se verán más motivados a ayudarte :)

Answer (score 1):

Para abrirlo como opción es realizar una copiar el archivo, y esta copia abrirla con un Intent que manipule archivos de tipo `"application/pdf"`, por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creamos un método para copiar el archivo del directorio `/raw` a el almacenamiento externo:

```
private void CopyRawToSDCard(int id, String path) {
    InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(id);
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(path);
    byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
    int read = 0;
        while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
            out.write(buff, 0, read);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
        Log.i(TAG, "copyFile, success!");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "copyFile FileNotFoundException " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "copyFile IOException " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Para abrir el archivo, copiamos y lo abrimos mediante un Intent:

```
   CopyRawToSDCard(R.raw.miarchivo, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/miarchivo.pdf" );

      File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/miarchivo.pdf" );//File path
        if (pdfFile.exists()){ //Revisa si el archivo existe!
            Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            //define el tipo de archivo
            intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
            intent.setFlags(Intent. FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            //Inicia pdf viewer
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No existe archivo! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: Gracias en cuanto lo pruebe le digo.